# BigQuery Javascript UDF fails with "Resources Exceeded"

Tags: google-bigquery, udf

This questions is probably another instance of

[BigQuery UDF memory exceeded error on multiple rows but works fine on single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518347/bigquery-udf-memory-exceeded-error-on-multiple-rows-but-works-fine-on-single-row/36390087#36390087)

But it was suggested that I post as a question instead of an answer.

I'm using javascript to parse logfiles into a table.  The javascript parse function is relatively simple.  It works at 1M rows but fails at 3M rows.  Log files can be a lot bigger than the 3M so failing is a problem.

The function is below.

```
function parseLogRow(row, emit) {

    r =  (row.logrow ? row.logrow : "") + (row.l2 ? " " + row.l2 : "") + (row.l3 ? " " + row.l3 : "")
    ts = null
    category = null
    user = null
    message = null
    db = null
    seconds = null
    found = false
    if (r) {
        m = r.match(/^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^\]]*)\] ::( \(([\d\.]+)s\))? (.*)/ )
        if( m){
          ts = new Date(m[1])*1
          category = m[3] || null
          user = m[4] || null
          db = m[5] || null
          seconds = m[7] || null
          message = m[8] || null
          found = true
        }
        else {
          message = r
          found = false
        }
     }

    emit({
      ts:  ts,
      category: category,
      user: user,
      db: db,
      seconds: seconds*1.0,
      message: message,
      found: found
      });
  }


  bigquery.defineFunction(
    'parseLogRow',                           // Name of the function exported to SQL
    ['logrow',"l2","l3"],                    // Names of input columns
    [
      {'name': 'ts', 'type': 'float'},  // Output schema
      {'name': 'category', 'type': 'string'},
      {'name': 'user', 'type': 'string'},
      {'name': 'db', 'type': 'string'},
      {'name': 'seconds', 'type': 'float'},
      {'name': 'message', 'type': 'string'},
      {'name': 'found', 'type': 'boolean'},
    ],
    parseLogRow                          // Reference to JavaScript UDF
  );
```

I'm referencing the function with this query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as row_num,
    ts,category,user,
    db,seconds,message,found,
FROM parseLogRow((SELECT * FROM[#{dataset}.today]
      LIMIT 1000000
    ))
```

Some example data in the 'today' table looks like this (as a CSV):

```
logrow,l2,l3
# Logfile created on 2015-12-29 00:00:09 -0800 by logger.rb/v1.2.7,,
2015-12-29 00:00:09.262 -0800 [INFO|7aaa0|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:09.277 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaa0|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:09.278 -0800 [INFO|7aaa0|] :: Completed scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:14.343 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaa2|scheduler] :: Polling for pending tasks (master: true),,
2015-12-29 00:00:19.396 -0800 [INFO|7aaa4|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:19.409 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaa4|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:19.410 -0800 [INFO|7aaa4|] :: Completed scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:29.487 -0800 [INFO|7aaa6|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:29.500 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaa6|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:29.500 -0800 [INFO|7aaa6|] :: Completed scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:39.597 -0800 [INFO|7aaa8|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:39.610 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaa8|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:39.611 -0800 [INFO|7aaa8|] :: Completed scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:44.659 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaaa|scheduler] :: Polling for pending tasks (master: true),,
2015-12-29 00:00:49.687 -0800 [INFO|7aaac|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:49.689 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaac|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:49.689 -0800 [INFO|7aaac|] :: Completed scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:59.869 -0800 [INFO|7aaae|] :: Running scheduled job: confirm running gulp process,,
2015-12-29 00:00:59.871 -0800 [DEBUG|7aaae|] :: Restarted gulp process,,
```

This is a bit of a hack as I'm importing the log as a 3 column table (really, just one column) by importing it as a CSV with the delimiter set to tab (we usually don't have any tabs in the log file), the using a query to turn it into the table I actually want.

I like this pattern because it the parsing is fast and distributed (when it works).

A job that failed is: bigquery-looker:bquijob_260be029_153dd96cfdb.  Please contact me if you need a reproducible case.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point # 1
I dont see issue with UDF - it worked for me even on 10M rows
I think the issue rather is in use of ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - remove it and it should work!

```
SELECT
  ts,category,user,
  db,seconds,message,found,
FROM parseLogRow((SELECT * FROM[#{dataset}.today]
))
```

Point #2
From performance prospective, below should run faster (I think) and in general I would suggest avoid using UDF in cases when "plain" BQ works as well

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(logrow, r'^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^\]]*\] :: .*') AS ts,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(logrow, r'^(?:\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[([^|]*)\|(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^\]]*)\] :: (?:.*)') AS category,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(logrow, r'^(?:\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[(?:[^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|(?:[^\]]*)\] :: (?:.*)') AS user,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(logrow, r'^(?:\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^|]*)\|([^\]]*)\] :: (?:.*)') AS db,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(logrow, r'^(?:\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^\]]*)\] :: (.*)') AS message,
  REGEXP_MATCH(logrow, r'^((?:\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d (?:\+|\-)\d\d\d\d) \[(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^|]*)\|(?:[^\]]*)\] :: (?:.*))') AS found
FROM (
  SELECT logrow +IFNULL(' ' + l2, '') + IFNULL(' ' + l3, '') AS logrow 
  FROM YourTable    
)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are exactly right.  Wasn't the javascript it was the window function.  Here is more info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247703/rank-or-row-number-in-bigquery-over-a-large-dataset